# How to split a string into an array using a given regex expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to `explode / preg_split` a string so that I get an array of all the values that are enclosed in `( )`. I've tried the following code but I always get an empty array, I have tried many things but I cant seem to do it right

Could anyone spot what am I missing to get my desired output?

```
$pattern = "/^\(.*\)$/";
$string = "(y3,x3),(r4,t4)";
$output = preg_split($pattern, $string);
print_r($output);
```

Current output `Array ( [0] => [1] => )`

Desired output `Array ( [0] => "(y3,x3)," [1] => "(r4,t4)" )`

Comment: Is it necessary in your situation to have ^ and $ in your regex? I tried with an Ungreedy group catching version of your regex.. have a look here http://regex101.com/r/fL6pN5/1

Comment: You have to use `preg_match_all`, not `preg_split`

Comment: @Jonathan Thurft it's important to mention that the usage of lookbehind and lookahead impacts on the performance. For a js performance test you can check it [here](http://jsperf.com/test-regex-so-24562713)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `preg_split()` your regex should be matching the **delimiters** within the string to split the string into an array. Your regex is currently matching the **values**, and for that, you can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all), like so:

```
$pattern = "/\(.*?\)/";
$string = "(y3,x3),(r4,t4)";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $output);
print_r($output[0]);
```

This [outputs](http://3v4l.org/ZB96L#v430):

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => (y3,x3) 
    [1] => (r4,t4) 
)
```

If you want to use `preg_split()`, you would want to match the `,` between `),(`, but without consuming the parenthesis, like so:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=\)),(?=\()/";
$string = "(y3,x3),(r4,t4)";
$output = preg_split($pattern, $string);
print_r($output);
```

This uses a [positive lookbehind and positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find the `,` between the two parenthesis groups, and split on them. It also output the same as the above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple regex like `\B,\B` to split the string and improve the performance by avoiding lookahead or lookbehind regex.

`\B` is a non-word boundary so it will match only the `,` between `)` and `(`

Here is a working example:

http://regex101.com/r/cV7bO7/1

```
$pattern = "/\B,\B/";
$string = "(y3,x3),(r4,t4),(r5,t5)";
$result = preg_split($pattern, $string);
```

**$result** will contain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (y3,x3)
    [1] => (r4,t4)
    [2] => (r5,t5)
)
```

Comment: +1, Very good idea. Since the format is well know, it seems to be the simplest way.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte glad you like it. Thanks for +1 :))